# Outlook Addin can't send request to the AppDomain

Tags: outlook-web-addins, gpo

I have an Outlook Web Addin. We deployed it on several hundreds of accounts for a customer with Microsoft 365 E3 licenses.

For most accounts the addin loads, and a call is sent to our backend server.

The domain of the backend and of the storage (two different domains) are declared in AppDomain in the manifest.

For a few others, the addin appears in the ribbon, but the web HTTPS call never arrives. We made a simple Hello World Addin with just one web call to be sure it does not come from our code - with the same results. But in both cases : our addin do work on Outlook on the web, from the same computer and account. We opened our backend domain with IE 11 and it works.

What else can block a web addin in Outlook to communicate with an external domain ? As it is supposed to use the IE11 engine, how an addin can work on IE11 and not on Desktop. What parameters (GPO ? Trusted sites / domains ?) should I investigate ?

**Update**

1. We moved the addin to the same domain of the backend, to check if it could be linked to Cross Domains requests. Same result : call never ends.
2. We checked the customer proxy : all used domains are accessible.

** Update **

Screenshot of message : [image: Error message in Outlook desktop]

Comment: Not sure how your frontend and backend communicate. Maybe this issue is unique to your add-in, or the customer's environment. Let an impacted customer install our test add-in (https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa200001603?tab=overview). Afterwards, open an email and click on the **Code** button in the ribbon to open the code editor. Click on the menu hamburger button, then New Snippet. Copy/paste this code into the editor: https://pastebin.com/h3xG31pr. Close the window. In the ribbon, click on **Run**, then *Run* button in the taskpane. Does the request fail or succeed?

Comment: Do you know the versions of Outlook and Windows on the impacted machines? This can determine which browser Outlook uses to render the add-in (as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins)), and can sometimes explain differences between machines. And just to clarify, when running the add-in in Outlook on the Web, was Outlook on the Web launched in IE?

Comment: Thanks, very useful debug addin indeed ! I am currently testing with a very simple gist and come back with mre elements. @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT , we tested the addin both in IE 11 and Edge where it works.

Comment: What code do you use to send the web request? Since it works for some users but not others, I would check a network trace from the user's machine to determine if the request is made (and fails before it gets to your server), and if that doesn't help to check any console logs that could contain an error, or check for any error returned by the JS code making the request. Collecting the Windows and Outlook versions from the affected machine would help determine if that's a difference between the working and non-working cases.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT , is there a known compatibility issue for Outlook Addin with Windows 10 LTSB versions ?

Comment: No, we are not aware of specific issues with Windows 10 LTSB versions. This likely means that the older (old Edge or IE11) browswer engine is being used for addins. It will still be useful to get the build version for Windows and Office to investigate further. Also, earlier you indicated that addin works in IE11 and Edge - is that test using OWA (Outlook online)?

Comment: Yes it means using OWA : it always works with OWA. I am investigating something : would it change anything if we buy an EV SSL certificate ? Could it change the way the website is "considered" by IE11, and consequently gaining trust ? It is trange that the same addin files do work on some accounts when they are hosted on a blob.core.windows.net domain and not on our domain.

Comment: I assume you are still following up, but are you able to find any common build numbers among users that are having the issue, and users who are NOT having an issue? (this will hopefully help us follow up with internal partner teams who may know if there is an issue)

Comment: Following up, the HTTP calls from the add-in shouldn't be intercepted inside Outlook, so it's not clear why the web requests aren't going through. Does using Fiddler show the web request and what error occured?

Comment: When using Fiddler on my own account (perfectly working), the addin cannot be launched (red cross)- there is something that is blocking the addin to be opened, but I don't know what. Is there something special to configure with Fiddler so it does load the web addins ? @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: More details : moving from a mail to another in outlook generates a call in fiddler. But lauching the addin does nothing.

Comment: Can we please get the Outlook and Windows version numbers of the users that are having issues? Also, is your add-in a task pane add-in? If so, would it be possible to take a screenshot of an impacted machine's Outlook after clicking on the add-in's ribbon button. (Be sure to remove any private data).

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I added a screenshot in the description. Just checked with Fiddler finally : no trace of a call to get the html taskpane addin file - whereas I can see the call on my own machine. It seems the addin is clocked before sending any call.

Comment: Office version : 16.0.11929.20974 and 16.0.12527.21504 on some computers.

Comment: Thank you for adding the screenshot and providing the builds. Is the screenshot the error from using Fiddler or the error you see when trying to make the call to get the html on the effected machines? If the former, do you see any errors when loading the add-in?